# ServiceStack Method not found: 'System.String ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IContentTypeFilter.GetFormatContentType(System.String)'

Tags: servicestack

After update to 3.9.54.0 from 3.9.37.0
Error raised on /api
Method not found: 'System.StringServiceStack.ServiceHost.IContentTypeFilter.GetFormatContentType(System.String)'.

Comment: Have you added reference to `ServiceStack.ServiceHost`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update "Service Clients and Common libs for ServiceStack projects" package.